# How to display application title in XAML text field

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone page code that is shared by multiple applications.

At the top of the page, I show the title of the application, like so:

Is it possible to make the text be bound to the application title as defined in the application's assembly?

I realise that I could do this by code by reading the title in the assembly and then doing something like:

```
this.ApplicationTitle.Text = title;
```

I was hoping that the title as defined in the assembly could be accessed with some magic like:

```
Text={assembly title}" directly from within the xaml.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a property called ApplicationTitle that returns that name of the application like the following, and then bind to it in XAML:

```
public string ApplicationTitle
{
    get { return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name; }
}
```

(You can use a relative binding source if you can't or don't want to use the data context.)

**edit:**

I just realized that my method involved security considerations since GetName is a method that is [Security Critical]. And I got a MethodAccessException stating: Attempt to access the method failed: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()

So here's another way to get the assembly name and return it in a property by using the AssemblyTitle attribute.

```
public string ApplicationTitle
{
    get
    {
        System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute ata =
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0] as System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute;
        return ata.Title;
    }
}
```

To bind in XAML, you can use this:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=Parent.ApplicationTitle}"
```

Comment: I started down that path too, and created a static property ApplicationTitle in the Application class. However, I'm yet to find a way to call it from the XAML that the compiler doesn't choke on or actually give me something else than an empty text

Comment: Your method would required to define the ApplicationTitle property in every page where I want to refer to the title. that's not what I want to do

Comment: How about creating a **base class** that inherits from PhoneApplicationPage and that contains the property and use that in your applications? Regarding your first comment, yes, the property should be static but the compiler doesn't choke on the above.